# How to share an injected and populated javax.enterprise.context.SessionBean among javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped beans in a JSF WebApp?

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

I am injecting a CDI `@ javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` bean in a JSF `@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` bean. In the view bean, I have set some values in the session bean pojo. After redirecting to a new page, older view bean goes out of scope and a new view bean comes in scope. How do I really access previously set session bean in the new view bean?

I injected the same session bean in the new view bean, but the session bean is now empty as it seems that it has re-initialized in the new view bean. Please let me know how do I access the previously populated session bean?

Comment: It should work just fine as you expected. Apparently it's either actually not a session scoped bean (perhaps the scope annotation is imported from wrong package? at least your FQN is incorrect), or the physical session got destroyed/recreated/lost in the meanwhile (track it in browser's HTTP traffic monitor).

Comment: @BalusC FQN seems alright and Session Id does not change throughout in Cookie Storage section of browser console. `@javax.inject.Named`, `@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` & `@javax.inject.Inject` is coming from javaee-api-7.0.jar. And `@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` is coming from jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final.jar. I logged object hashcode through logger in no arg constructor of session bean pojo. After redirection, I see in logs that maybe injection in second view is resulting in creation of new object (new hashcode) by proxy.